# JavaFX+Swing: additional checks if code is executed on correct UI thread

Tags: swing, javafx

This question is about integration of JavaFX and Swing (using both inside one application).

Is there an option to enable additonal checks if the code is executed on the correct UI thread, possibly via a JVM argument? I remember that I've read something about it, but cannot find it again.

I'm *not* looking for `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()` and `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()`.

I'm looking for a Java Runtime flag that enables additional checks/assertment in the JavaFX and Swing framework code. Possibly there are additional checks that are disabled by default for performance reasons.

Comment: For JavaFX it's `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()`

Comment: @devpuh, sorry my question was not clear, I have updated it.

Comment: no there is no such flag: many properties in the fx realm are always automatically checked, for swing there's nothing (except in some LFs like Substance which enforces the EDT)

Comment: [`CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager) may help for Swing.